# ConfigParser section creation

Tags: python, python-3.x

If `config.add_section('main')` from `ConfigParser` is executed multiple times, targeting same file will that cause an error like having multiple `main` sections or it will just skip creating section if it already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConfigParser` object can be seen as a dictonary (section) of dictionaries (option/option values).

Using `add_section` twice on the same name raises an exception

```
import configparser

s = configparser.ConfigParser()
s.add_section("main")
s.add_section("main")
```

gives:

```
configparser.DuplicateSectionError: Section 'main' already exists
```

workaround check if section exists, add only if it doesn't:

```
def add_section_no_matter_what(s,section_name):
   if not s.has_section(section_name):
      s.add_section(section_name)
```

useful in an helper function to create section if not already exists, else use the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the documentation of `configparser.ConfigParser.add_section`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.add_section):

> `add_section(section)`
>   Add a section named section to the instance. **If a section by the given name already exists, `DuplicateSectionError` is raised.**